# Join between User and Locations table

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have zip codes stored in the Users table, and in the Locations table I have **lat, lon**, and **the zips** data from all 50 states.

I am trying to finish this line:

```
:geo => [current_user.latitude * Math::PI / 180.0, current_user.longitude * Math::PI / 180.0]
```

The issue is the User stores zip code only. How can I define so that **current_user.latitude** would show the latitude based on the current users zip code?

Comment: As a for instance, you can use USPS data sets which have information correlating geo references with mail addresses and zip codes. Overall it is not a simple calculation - it is a complex look up.. Postal data set information for mass mailers testing: https://www.usps.com/postalone/testing.htm

Comment: That would be much more than what I am looking to do. I just want to output the latitude and longitude values (stored in Locations table that includes zips with lat/lon) from the current users zip code. I have the relationship between Users and Locations, and the data imported. USPS data sets would not be helpful for this situation. Thanks though!

Comment: You can use the geocoder api to get the latitude and longitude. But then it would have to be a proper zip code. unlike countries like America , if you enter the zip code as 742 and the country as India, you would get lots of records.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely clear on the structure of your `locations` table, but what about something like the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def location
    @location ||= Location.where(zip: zipcode)
  end

  def latitude
    location.lat
  end

  def longitude
    location.lon
  end
end
```

The real issue is how you have to construct the join between your `users` table and your `locations` table. If they each have a column which contains a string of the ZIP code, it just requires a simply `where` condition like the one shown in `User#location` above.